# Custom Translator - Documents are not available after uploading

Tags: microsoft-translator

After I create a project and I upload successfully a TMX in Documents (I can see it in Upload history and in Documents), when I open the project again there are no Documents available and I can't create the model.
I've seen that in the Quickstart examples there are checkboxes next to the name of the projects and of the documents but in my case they are not available. 
Moreover, my TMX source language is EN-GB and the language specification appears in "Language(s)"(ex. English - (United Kingdom )-Italian); whereas when I select the language pair in "Upload Files" I can select only English without United Kingdom or US. Do you think this could be the problem?

Does anyone have any ideas/solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, your question has been flagged for review (because you're new and this is just a single paragraph). I don't know much about ms-translator, but this is a community for programmers, so: is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Culture is not yet supported. Your guess is right on; "EN-GB" is the problem. Change it to "EN-US" would fix it.

-Mohamed